# How are FPGAs and MCUs programmed

Tags: microcontroller, fpga

FPGA and MCU evaluation boards have typically a micro USB JTAG interface that allows the PC to load the "code" into the unit.

Can the FPGA or MCU also be programmed with I2C or SPI via a PC? If yes, why are these protocols almost never used and JTAG is used to program a FPGA, MCU with a PC?

Thanks

Comment: Some FPGAs can boot themselves over SPI from a Flash ROM. But I don't recall seeing one loaded by an MCU that way. Then the ROM is programmed via JTAG.

Comment: Read the documentation of the **specific parts** you are interested in.  All responses so far contain as many erroneous points as accurate ones, but _generalizing_ across such a broad topic is unworkable anyway.

Comment: The main reason the eval boards come with an onboard USB->JTAG IC is so you can actually debug them. They're eval boards, so they want to make the experience as user-friendly as possible to the programmer.

I know first hand, for example, that NXP/Freescale's RT10XX series has built in programming modes for I2C, SPI, and USB. But it really depends on the specific device you're using.

Comment: The MCU or FPGA can be programmed using the protocols/interfaces documented by the MCU or FPGA vendor.  What part of the documentation are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To program (or configure for an FPGA) with protocols like UART, I2C, or SPI, the MCU or FPGA already needs bootloading software (or configuration bitstream for an FPGA) on it to let it program itself. If you lose or corrupt this bootloader then you obviously can't use this method.

A JTAG can program a blank MCU, or an MCU in any state of corruption.

FPGAs don't use bootloaders because FPGAs don't switch context so easily between the bootloader and main program, being all hardware/no software in nature.

For an FPGA, you might directly write to the external ROM using either a JTAG or an MCU (which in turn might be connected to the PC via USB). This is done in various ways depending on the ROM's communication (usually parallel or SPI). Or you can use a JTAG or microcontroller (which in turn might be connected to the PC via USB) to write to the external ROM through the FPGA such that the JTAG or MCU do not need a direct connection to the external ROM.

Comment: So in case of the FPGA, the PC loads a bootloader into the FPGAs ROM?

Comment: Your comments about FPGAs are rather mistaken; it would be worthwhile to review the actual manufacturer literature.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Pretty sure that's where I actually got it from since I don't know any other place to get it from. Which part in particular are you saying is mistaken?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Well I am literally looking at right now at the Artix 7 literature and do not see any large discrepencies

Comment: @ChrisStratton Are you referring to the part for the temporary configuration that the JTAG or MCU can use to enable the ROM to be written through the FPGA? From what I'm reading for the Artix and Spartan, this appears to be dedicated circuitry rather than a bitstreanm.

Comment: That and everything else too.   You've not represented the actual facts with any useful clarity but rather posted a combination of wrong guesses and mixed up details.  The question is too broad to be answerable anyway, but erroneous half-answers are not useful.

Answer (score 0):

FPGAs are almost always JTAG but MCUs not so much.  Many have proprietary programming protocols and interfaces.

As far as programming over other interfaces, and USB is an example, a bootloader can be flashed using the native interface for the MCU and then that can take programming instructions from USB, I2C, USART, even network/WiFi is the device supports that.